# what variable can i use to identify a specific pages

Tags: theming

i need to load a diff stylesheet depending upon which page the user is on.

when using: 
     themename_preprocess_page(){kpr(&$variables;)}

i thought i'd see a pageId or pageTitle in which i could use for a conditional statement but i'm not seeing those variables. am i overlooking something? what can i use to uniquely identify a page so i can the use drupal_add_css()?

i guess i could do at the node level? but the stylesheet i need to load is really a page level thing.

can someone advise on the best way to do? big thanks in advance

Comment: i think maybe my theme was somehow not outputting a page title variable, i see that now when switching page to Bartik.

Answer (score 1):

You may have trouble adding CSS with drupal_add_css in `hook_preprocess_page` because the `$styles` variable has already been built.

Better to add CSS in `hook_preprocess_html` or `hook_page_build`

Note, you should be able to target specific pages in CSS by using body classes.

e.g:

```
body.page-node-type-article #content{
  background-color:pink;
}
```

But yes, to check the path, you can use

```
$arg = arg($index); // system path component
$path = current_path(); // full base system path ($_GET['q']);
$alias = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // full alias only
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [arg](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) to identify specific page.

It returns a component of the current Drupal path.

When viewing a page at the path "**admin/structure/types**", for example, arg(0) returns "admin", arg(1) returns "structure", and arg(2) returns "types".

For more info go through the documentation.

Comment: thanks i will try. for some reason it seems that 'page title' is not part $variables in my custom theme. not sure why?

Comment: if i do echo arg(1) it outputs an integer

Comment: No, It will return menu callback's second part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
if ( preg_match('(^comment/reply/[0-9]*)', current_path())  === 1 ) {}
if ( preg_match('(^node/[0-9]*$)', current_path())  === 1 ) {}
if ( current_path() == 'search' ) {}
```

Using themename_preprocess_html, I think works fine. But I'm not sure if you need this exactly.
However, is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

[hook_init()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) is best function to make changes at page level. You can use arg() function to get arguments of current page. Even you can also use [menu_get_object()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) to get all possible values on rendered page.

Comment: hook_init() gets called for every non-cached request that Drupal handles, which isn't always an HTML page.  There are better options for pages, like `hook_page_build()`.